# Zooming in/out logic with RapaelJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, fullscreen

So when you set a flash object to 100% width/height what ends up happening is the flash movie zooms in as you stretch it out and make the window bigger. Well maybe that isn't what is happening, but it looks that way.

I am trying to achieve something similar with RaphaelJS. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/soparrissays/2rqtL/3/ , I have a simple example where the circle shrinks and expands as you make the result window bigger; however, it does it backwards. The circle should become larger as the window increases in size rather than get smaller. Can anyone spot what is happening here?

I am attempting to use setViewBox to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewBox is the area that you can see. You don't want this to change - you want to be able to see the original 800*600 area regardless of scale. If my canvas is 800 * 600, I always want to see this space. What I want to do is scale the 800*600 area to fit inside the visible region. You can do this by resizing the canvas to fit the window and setting the viewBox to a static 800 x 600.

**See**: http://jsfiddle.net/WgTuF/1/

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if im exactly correct, but one solution is as below.

What i have did is, i took the maximized window's `innerwidth` as `centPercentWidth`.

Then `onresize` of the window, im finding how much times the current window width will give the width of the maximized window.This is done through

`var times = centPercentWidth/width;`.

After that i have a variable `adjust`, which is for tweaking the exaggeration of the effect.
You may change this value, and see how the resize effects vary from value to value. For now its one(default behaviour).

Then we are finding the value of thrid and fourth parameter of the viewBox using `times` varible.(c and d).

Placed a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/89Qsx/

Try resizing the median in the fiddle.